# Trying to create dynamic curved lines with nunjucks and aframe template.

Tags: aframe

I have a very entry level of Javascript and building components for Aframe and I'm trying to get my head around why the following is not working.

I'm trying to create points that can be set with data inputs and connect them with a curved line. So far this is what I have:

```
<a-assets>
    <script id="datapoint" type="text/nunjucks">
        <a-entity position="{{ point }}">
            <a-box></a-box>
        </a-entity>
        <a-curve id="{{ trackid }}" type="type:QuadraticBezier">
            <a-curve-point position="{{ curve1 }}"></a-curve-point>
            <a-curve-point position="{{ curve2 }}"></a-curve-point>
            <a-curve-point position="{{ curve3 }}"></a-curve-point>
        </a-curve>
        <a-draw-curve mixin="curvedline" curveref="{{ trackid }}"></a-draw-curve>
        <a-entity mixin="cloneline" clone-along-curve="curve:{{ trackid }};"></a-entity>
        <a-entity mixin="movingNode" scale="{{scale}}" alongpath="curve:{{ trackid }}; loop:{{ repeat }}; delay:{{ wait }}; dur:{{ duration }}"></a-entity>
    </script>
</a-assets>

<a-entity id="inputPoint" 
          template="src: #datapoint" 
          data-point="0 10 5" 
          data-curve1="0 10 5" 
          data-curve2="0 5 0" 
          data-curve3="0 0 -5" 
          data-trackid="#track1" 
          data-scale="1 1 1" 
          data-repeat="true" 
          data-wait="1000" 
          data-duration="1000">
</a-entity>
```

It is creating the boxes however it won't use the position points of eg.
 {{curve-1}}

It only works if I remove the  section in the script and define them with a set id:

```
 < <a-curve id="track1" type="type:QuadraticBezier">
            <a-curve-point position="0 10 5"></a-curve-point>
            <a-curve-point position="0 0 0"></a-curve-point>
            <a-curve-point position="0 0 -10"></a-curve-point>
</a-curve> 

<a-assets>
    <script id="datapoint" type="text/nunjucks">
        <a-entity position="{{ point }}">
            <a-box></a-box>
        </a-entity>
        <a-draw-curve mixin="curvedline" curveref="{{ trackid }}"></a-draw-curve>
        <a-entity mixin="cloneline" clone-along-curve="curve:{{ trackid }};"></a-entity>
        <a-entity mixin="movingNode" scale="{{scale}}" alongpath="curve:{{ trackid }}; loop:{{ repeat }}; delay:{{ wait }}; dur:{{ duration }}"></a-entity>
    </script>
</a-assets>

<a-entity id="inputPoint" 
          template="src: #datapoint" 
          data-point="0 10 5" 
          data-curve1="0 10 5" 
          data-curve2="0 5 0" 
          data-curve3="0 0 -5" 
          data-trackid="#track1" 
          data-scale="1 1 1" 
          data-repeat="true" 
          data-wait="1000" 
          data-duration="1000">
</a-entity>
```

Could someone please help me and tell me what I'm not getting or doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is "{{ trackid }}" not injecting a string in a string?
What does your console print when you open your developer tools?

Comment: It outputs alot of aframe errors, all starting with the following: 

"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

In the Elements tab however it outputs the data-curve positions when I set a custom trackID correctly, it is just not showing the actual curve.

Comment: Do the other template variables work? What happens if you hard-code the positions in the template? What version of A-Frame + Template? Looks like you also don't need Nunjucks and can use the default template string templating `position="${curve1}"`.

Comment: Hi @ngokevin, 

Hard coding the positions instead of eg. ${curve1} does output correctly but is not working either. 

I'm running the master A-Frame and the latest template code. 

It looks like it works without Nunjucks! Converted all "{{}}" to "${}" and same things work and break it seems. Only now the scene is rendered white with the webVR UI showing.

Comment: Sorry, got confused. It outputs correctly, but does not work? And it works without Nunjucks, but it breaks?

Comment: I'm sorry, please allow me to clarify. 

When I try to use the "curve-points" inside the script, as shown in the first code example. It will not draw the lines in the scene visually. However, upon inspecting. The position numbers of the "data-curve" are in the html. Hence, outputting correctly but not working. 

Without Nunjucks, the 2nd example works. The one with the "curve-points" outside the script. But when I try the first example. The scene visually renders white and only shows the A-Frame/WebVR UI what was not happening with Nunjucks. 

I hope this is more clear.

Comment: Can you post an example on Glitch.com? I can poke around. There's a lot of stuff happening so hard to debug it by staring at the code (especially since we can't see the curve components).

Comment: I don't have glitch.com but you can see the code on the github I use:

https://github.com/mmguide/mmguide.github.io/blob/master/webvr/projectflare/supplychainvr.html

Thanks for helping me out!  :)

Comment: No account needed. If you go to glitch.com/~aframe in browser, click remix, and copy-and-paste your code in, I can remix it and modify it and show possible solution without having to fetch/install your GitHub :)

Comment: oh this is very nice! Thanks! Does this work for you? https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/f5e21fc5-efb9-4f3c-8251-9897ef010b8e

Answer (score 0):

First thing I found was your project has a bit of a typo. There is an extra `#` prepended to the ID. It was rendering like `<a-curve id="#track1" type="type:QuadraticBezier">` when it should be `id="track1"`. I've updated to the Glitch https://glitch.com/edit/#!/polite-wrench to pass into the template `track1` instead of `#track1` and prepend the `#` where needed.

I also saw the layout component was being required indirectly. Use the CDN links rather than copy-pasting the raw JS which is Webpacked.

Still some errors left though and the white lines aren't rendering, but that's a step forward.

Comment: I see, thanks! I got the lines to draw when I place the "curve-points' outside the script with your type fix! :) So does this mean you cannot put this in the script? I'm going to try some other things now.

I use the raw JS because it seems to load rather slow when I open the file locally.

Comment: It should work, would need to dig into it more to see what's happening. I stopped looking at it once I resolved that first issue.